# Getting Windows 8 UI Control to fill entire horizontal space

Tags: windows, xaml, visual-c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

For a Windows 8 Metro app, I have a Rectangle inside of a Canvas inside of the main Grid, such that:

```
<Grid>
...
  <Canvas>
    <Rectangle />
    ...
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

How would I make the rectangle dynamically take up the width of the screen?

Comment: Would it work to wrap the Canvas in a `<ViewBox Scale="UniformToFill">`?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas does not constrain or change its children's size or positions. If you want your rectangle to be as long as the screen width I recommend to put it inside the Grid, as the Grid has the size you need for the Rectangle (with HorizontalAlignment="Strech"). Or you might bind Rectangle.Width to Grid.ActualWidth.

Comment: With the way it's configured in the original question, setting the rectangle's width doesn't work. Is there a way to define a rectangle's width by percentage or something?

Comment: The closest for "percentage" you're asking for exists for Columns and Rows, but in Grid. Did you try to do the binding?

Comment: Nestor is right, Canvas is the wrong panel to place the Rectangle in for it to be scaled, it should be within a Grid.

Comment: I need to use canvas since I need a way to determine the absolute position of the inner rectangle. Unless you know of another way to get the absolute position of the rectangle without using canvas, I have to put the rectangle inside the canvas.

Comment: You can use a RenderTransform for absolute positioning no matter the panel.